# How to count the no of feature files whose all of the scenario outlines passed?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am new to Cucumber. I am doing the following using Java code / in team city build (i.e automatically with no manual intervention)

1. I generate feature files that contain maximum three Scenario Outlines
2. I count the number of feature files generated and run the feature files
3. Is there any inbuilt Cucumber tags or something available to count all the **passed feature files**?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: U can look at using a custom formatter... Which version?

Comment: @Grasshopper - it is 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Custom formatter below will give the lists of feature files in which all steps have passed and also lists of feature files in which any step have failed. Implement the other methods with empty methods as required. Add this to the runner in the plugins options.

```
public class SuccessCounter implements Reporter, Formatter {

    private List<Feature> allScenarioPassedFeature;
    private List<Feature> anyScenarioFailedFeature;
    private boolean stepFailed;
    private Feature feature;

    public  SuccessCounter() {
        allScenarioPassedFeature = new ArrayList<Feature>();
        anyScenarioFailedFeature = new ArrayList<Feature>();
    }


    @Override
    public void result(Result arg0) {
        if(stepFailed==false && arg0.getStatus() != Result.PASSED)
            stepFailed = true;            
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("COUNTS");
        System.out.println("Passed - " + allScenarioPassedFeature.size());
        System.out.println("Failed - "+anyScenarioFailedFeature.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void eof() {
        if(stepFailed)
            anyScenarioFailedFeature.add(feature);
        else
            allScenarioPassedFeature.add(feature);
    }

    @Override
    public void feature(Feature arg0) {
        stepFailed = false;
        this.feature = arg0;
    }

}
```

Use at your own peril if u have parallel running.

Comment: thank you @Grasshopper. I will give a try and post how did I get on.

Comment: Which method should I call in the above and where should I call it? I see feature method taking Feature and result  method taking Result. Should I have to pass generated feature files in to feature(Feature arg0) ? Sorry since I am new to this I am asking these low level questions.

Comment: No need to call directly. Need to include in runner. https://automationrhapsody.com/create-cucumber-jvm-custom-formatter/